# CS-Cart and UNIX permissions

Tags: php, unix, file-permissions, cs-cart

I am installing CS-Cart software on Apache server and it does not work. I tried to follow instructions, but there is always an error: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE (as shown bellow).
[image: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE]
Before installation, we have to change permissions to this:
[image: Permissions]

Is it right, if I changed permissions of:
 - config.local.php to 666
 - (directories) design, images, var to 777
Should I do anything else? Sadly, I do not have an access to terminal and I have to change it manually.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open the config.local.php file and replace:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('DEVELOPMENT', true);
```

Then reload the page to see error text message.

Hope this will help